# Android addiing fragment to ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm pretty new to Android and wanted some help. My app has two tabs (as fragments) in a ViewPager. One of the tabs shows a list of items. On clicking on an item, the app should display the details of the item.

Now how do I this? Do I add the details in a third fragment? If so, how should I add the fragment? I do not want the details fragment to come as a tab inside ViewPager.

I tried adding the details fragment as a separate fragment to the ViewPager. On clicking an item, the fragment is being called (the log statements inside are displayed in console). However, I just get a blank screen.

This is my activity.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

This is the xml for the details fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="600dp"
    android:layout_height="700dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
...
</LinearLayout>
```

This is how I'm currently adding the details fragment from the Activity:

```
DetailsFragment details = new DetailsFragment();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.pager, details);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should open a new activity to display the details. This new activity will simply be a container for your `DetailsFragment`.

You need to pass the details to display to the `Activity` in its `Intent`, then the Activity will pass the details to the Fragment using the arguments Bundle (`Fragment.setArguments()`). Most of the time, this will be a simple object implementing `Parcelable`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried passing the data to a new activity and then starting a fragment from there. But now I'm getting a  java.lang.securityexception binder invocation to an incorrect interface.

Comment: Basically what I'm doing is I have an Interface in my ListFragment (i.e is the tab). On clicking on a listitem I have a call back method which passes a parceable object to it's parent activity. From the call back method in the parent activity, I get the object and start the new activity (which acts as container to my DetailsFragment) using Intent and pass the data using intent.putExtra. I get the error when I do startActivity(detailsIntent)

Comment: The problem occurs only when I add the parceable object to the intent. If I comment out that line, or pass some other argument like a String, the app works fine. I also tried adding the parceable object to a bundle, and then passing the bundle to the new intent. Still get same error. Why am I getting is this error? And is there any other way to send the object?

Comment: Parcelable is complex to implement properly, especially if you're mixing different types of objects in your list and use an interface. You can try to pass your data as Serializable instead of Parcelable (then cast it back). It's a bit less performant but you should not notice the performance impact.
However the exception you're getting back is definitely strange, like if you're trying to start another process or something like that. You should just call startActivity() and pass the Activity class and Parcelable extra.